# Issues with adding keyword arguments to the 'apply' function when used in conjunction with a 'groupby' on a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby, apply

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
            States             Col_A     Col_B      Col_C    
 ----------------------    ----------- ---------- ---------  
           Alabama              10        40          70    
           Alabama              5         30          60     
           Alabama              15        20          80   
           Alaska               20        50          80    
           Alaska               20        40          100
```

And I would to get sum(Col_A) * sum(Col_B) / sum(Col_C) where the sums are applied separately to each state, and place the results in a new column named Col_D. So basically it would look like:

```
            States             Col_A     Col_B      Col_C     Col_D
 ----------------------    ----------- ---------- --------- --------- 
           Alabama              10        40          70      12.86
           Alabama              5         30          60      12.86 
           Alabama              15        20          80      12.86
           Alaska               20        50          80      20
           Alaska               20        40          100     20
```

Where 12.86 is equal to (10+5+15)*(40+30+20)/(70+60+80).

I'm attempting to use:

```
my_df['Col_D'] = my_df.groupby('States').apply(lambda x: sum(x['Col_A'])*sum(x['Col_B'])/sum(x['Col_C']),result_type = 'broadcast')
```

but I get the error message:

```
<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'
```

This is very confusing to me, as I am trying to get the keyword argument result_type to be used for the apply function, not the lambda function. And when I try to apply the same logic on a regular dataframe (meaning no groupby) it works perfectly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for helper DataFrame with same size like original data filled by aggregate values and then processing by multiple and dividing:

```
df = my_df.groupby('States').transform('sum')
my_df['Col_D'] = df['Col_A'] * df['Col_B'] / df['Col_C']
print (my_df)
    States  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C      Col_D
0  Alabama     10     40     70  12.857143
1  Alabama      5     30     60  12.857143
2  Alabama     15     20     80  12.857143
3   Alaska     20     50     80  20.000000
4   Alaska     20     40    100  20.000000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df)
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
0     30     90    210
1     30     90    210
2     30     90    210
3     40     90    180
4     40     90    180
```

If want solution with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) create custom function, assign to new column and return all values of `x`:

```
def f(x):
    x['Col_D'] = x['Col_A'].sum() * x['Col_B'].sum()  / x['Col_C'].sum() 
    return x

df = my_df.groupby('States').apply(f)
print (df)
    States  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C      Col_D
0  Alabama     10     40     70  12.857143
1  Alabama      5     30     60  12.857143
2  Alabama     15     20     80  12.857143
3   Alaska     20     50     80  20.000000
4   Alaska     20     40    100  20.000000
```

Comment: So this definitely works, but is there a way to avoid the extra step? I'm mostly just very confused about how I would get the kernel to interpret the keyword argument 'result_type' to be used in the 'apply' function instead of the 'lambda' function.

Don't get me wrong, transform is a very useful function but it can't be used across columns of a dataframe. So if I needed to apply a more complicated function than my simple lambda example it would be really convenient to be able to use 'apply' instead of 'transform'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

It says result_type parameters works only if you set the parameter axis=1.

Comment: I believe that the axis is defaulted to 1 but even if I try to set the axis equal to 1 I get almost the exact same error message, only now it says:

    <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'